# Multiple grid view in multiple Tab issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am loading multiple grid view in multiple tab on page load ,there are 11 grid view which causing latency issue.

can you please tell me is there any another option to reduce latency, i am not able store that in session also because all the data was updating every time

```
 <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="div_created" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 400px" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="grd_created" runat="server"
            <%--*************--%>>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="div_inprocess" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 400px" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="grd_inprocess" runat="server"
            <%--*************--%>>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>
<%--*************--%>
<%--*************--%>
<div id="tabs-11">
    <div id="div1" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 400px" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            <%--*************--%>>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</div>


<ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
    <li runat="server" id="li_create" onclick="doAdelay()"><a href="#tabs-1">Created
        <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedCount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_proc" onclick="doAdelay()"><a href="#tabs-2">In Process
        <asp:Label ID="lblInprocessCount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_hold"><a href="#tabs-3">On Hold<asp:Label ID="lblonholdCount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>

    <li runat="server" id="li_comp"><a href="#tabs-4">Completed<asp:Label ID="lblcompltedCount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_fianl"><a href="#tabs-5">Finalized<asp:Label ID="lblFinalizedCount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_custom" visible="false"><a href="#tabs-6" runat="server"
        id="ViewCustom">Custom</a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_all"><a href="#tabs-7">All<asp:Label ID="lblAllcount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_SrchRslt" class="clssearch" visible="false"><a href="#tabs-8" runat="server"
        id="SrchRslt">Search Result<asp:Label ID="lblSearchcount" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_CR" visible="false"><a href="#tabs-9">In Rebuttal<asp:Label ID="lblCodeRebuttal" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_RR" visible="false"><a href="#tabs-10" runat="server"
        id="A1">Review Records<asp:Label ID="lblreviewrecords" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_SA" visible="false"><a href="#tabs-11" runat="server"
        id="A2">
        <asp:Label ID="lbltabSTA" runat="server" Text="Sent to Auditor"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblSA" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="li_PRS" visible="false"><a href="#tabs-12" runat="server"
        id="A3">Peer Review<asp:Label ID="lblpeerreviewS" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you should load each gridview when you click on corresponding tab.